# How to find out yum package names

Tags: centos, yum

Recently I needed to install `yum mbstring` but because I have two different versions of PHP installed I needed to install mbstring for php 5.5. Through some random google searches I figured out to run:

`yum install php55-php-mbstring.x86_64`

Is there an easier way of finding out the name of the package for specific php versions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general you don't need to search the whole internet for packages, you only need to select the correct package from the ones available in the repositories that are configured and enabled on the system concerned...

```
yum search mbstring
```

or if you prefer

```
yum list *mbstring*
```

or variations/refinements thereof as suggested in [`man yum`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)