# Name of missing screenshot rpm for CentOS 7.6 and how to find out

Tags: centos7, yum

I'm using a *CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)* instance that was stripped down to run off a thumb drive. Now I just need to capture a window.

My question is what *yum install* command would get me there? Is gnome-panel-screenshot what I need?

I tried to install gnome-utils, but

```
    # yum install gnome-utils 

    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: linux.mirrors.es.net
     * epel: sjc.edge.kernel.org
     * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
     * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
     * updates: mirror.keystealth.org

No package gnome-utils available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this led to the answer, found in [How to look up yum package names](https://serverfault.com/questions/811444/how-to-find-out-yum-package-names)

```
# yum search screenshot 

============================== N/S matched: screenshot ===
gnome-screenshot.x86_64 : A screenshot utility for GNOME
```

Followed by *yum install gnome-screenshot*, *man gnome-screenshot*, ...